# image_geometry Rectification -> remove black Pixels

Tags: ros, image-geometry, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I decided to do all Camera Stuff ith die image_geometry class provided by the opencv package.

Prior I rectified my camera image with:

getOptimalNewCameraMatrix
initUndistortRectifyMap
remap

This worked well, i could choose to show the black pixels at the edges or to cut an size the image so it only has valid pixels.

With image_geometry and the pinhole camera model class i don't see a way so rectify the image AND remove all regions with unvalid pixels.

Does someone know how?

THX

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37630/image_geometry-rectification--%3E-remove-black-pixels/) by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you just want to crop down the image to a certain Region of Interest.  This should be fairly straightforward to do by chaining together different pieces of the OpenCV library.

You probably already have an image with the [Mat type](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat).

You can then create a region of interest (ROI) using the [() Operator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id4)

So, something like:

```
Mat myImage;
Mat croppedImage = myImage(Range(50,100), Range(50,100));
```

Or, you could use a "Rect"

```
Mat myImage;
Rect myROI = Rect(50,100,50,100);
Mat croppedImage = myImage(myROI);
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0